# ASP .NET MVC & WebForms - Two projects and one final site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Is there a way to have a web site with some pages in ASP .NET MVC project and other (legacy pages) in ASP .NET Webforms in a way that the navigation is quite transparent to the final user?

Also, what happends with the URL?

I can't use a mix of web forms and mvc in the same project (althought i know it's possible)

[image: Architecture]

I want to use this approach to make the transition from web forms to mvc easier and whenever a new page is added put that page on the mvc project without affecting the current web forms working project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. One project = one website. You can technically deploy one or the other as a virtual application under the other, but this would still be two separate websites. They'd come up under the same domain/subdomain, but they would not be able to communicate with each other in terms of routing and such, i.e. there would be no way to get a URL for something in your MVC project from your Web Forms project.

MVC is backwards-compatible with Web Forms, so that you can migrate over to MVC *in-place*. In other words, you can add the MVC Nuget packages to a Web Forms project and start working with MVC in that same project while maintaining your existing Web Forms pages. *That* is how you do an upgrade. If you don't want to do it that way, your MVC site will have to be its own thing, hosted separately.

Answer (score 0):

- You can host the state in a SQL Server shared between the sites.
- You can have URLs in DB to have them in-sync between the sites. A start-up script of the MVC app could register its URLs automatically using the route collection.